# IE10 and jQuery: SCRIPT5009: "$" is undefined

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I'm faced with this really annoying problem, it appears in IE10 like in IE9. Given this HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Any Consult</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <script src="scripts/IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
```

This (scripts.js) works fine in FF and Chrome, but IE10 throws the SCRIPT5009 error.

scripts.js is like (simple, but tested example):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert('Hello');
});
```

IE10 does not load the jQuery-File and I tried nearly everything. I changed and reduced the filename, I spared the

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>...
```

part, I tried

```
src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"
```

but nothing happened. Because this is a new version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203846/jquery-1-6-1-ie9-and-script5009-is-undefined), I'd like to specify:

1. how should I name the jQuery-File for IE(10)?
2. where should I put the script tags in the HTML-Header?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Here the suggested HTML-version, which does not work, too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/clocks.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="scripts/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

IE9.js is a browser polyfill file.

And here is my screenshot ("ist undefiniert" means "is undefined", "Die Webseite reagiert nicht" means "the page went down", "Debugger beenden" means "stop debugging", $('.aLang') is a class in my HTML.

[image: Screenshot IE10 Bug Report]

Comment: try loading `jquery` in head and your `scripts.js` in body. might work sometimes. IE is a very weird browser with the weirdest of bugs

Comment: This didn't work for me either. Does this problem depends heavily on the specific (development) environment?!

Comment: could you go to dev tools in IE (press F12) and give us the screenshot of the console error? I know you mention the error here itself but jus a screenshot?

Comment: and what is `IE9.js`? what does it contain? it must contain only JS code, no jquery related stuff cos its before u load jquery. till that point when jquery is loaded, `$` will be `undefined`

Comment: @passionateCoder: You are right, but my problem is related to scripts.js, not to IE9.js. IE9.js is not loaded by my IE, because it is IE10.

Comment: could you try a [diff CDN](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js)? I know this is an off chance but try!!

Comment: off topic, but IE9.js is a patch script for IE8 and earlier; it is not required for IE9 itself, so you should say `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` rather than `lte IE 9`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem with IE and found that the jQuery javascript file was corrupt in the IE developer tool.  This was caused in my case by HTTP GZIP compression being done by the server but IE wasn't decompressing the file.  I guess that if you turn off static HTTP compression or exclude the application/x-javascript from whatever is doing the compression (Mine was done by FluorineFX for all files over 10Kb) it should work okay once you have cleared your browser cache to get rid of the compressed javascript file.

Comment: Could you describe how to fix it? How do I uncompress the file?

Answer (score 4):

Place the conditional script **after** the jQuery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script src="scripts/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't change anything. IE10 stays restive.

Comment: Can you post a sample page?