# SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined for IE only - jQuery is already installed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, internet-explorer

Trying to build a heatmap on Google Maps via Yeoman. It works totally fine in all other browsers apart from IE. Does not function in IE 10 all the way to Edge. Edge doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't work.

Error is the standard '$' is undefined:

```
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined
```

I have jQuery installed into the `<head>` and alongside the scripts at the bottom just incase there  are any scripts running before jQuery, but I'm having no luck what-so-ever. Any ideas why?

**URL:** http://dmhost.co.uk/zoetis/googlemap/index.html

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882513/ie10-and-jquery-script5009-is-undefined

Comment: I am not seeing jquery file in network tab. Did you changed it's name?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on my Chrome either. I also get the same error. jQuery simply isn't loaded.

Comment: I have this in the head "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>" could it possibly be ignored by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

Basically, I'm an idiot.
I was placing the jquery script inside this section of the head tag:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
<script src="/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This means the jquery was being removed during the 'gulp-build' process.

Sorry for the time-wasting here guys!
Charlie