# Selenium throwing error "SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' " when using Jquery

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following code to execute jquery in selenium. I am getting the below error even after changing many jquery min files.

```
Error : SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
```

Code :

```
String mouseOverScript1 = "var script = document.createElement('script');"
        +"script.src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js';"
        +"script.type = 'text/javascript';"
        +"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript1);
String mouseOverScript2 = "var script = document.createElement('script');"
                +"script.src ='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js';"
                +"script.type = 'text/javascript';"
                +"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript2);
String mouseOverScript3 = "var script = document.createElement('script');"
                +"script.src ='•http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.map';"
                +"script.type = 'text/javascript';"
                +"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript3);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$(\"#ctrlHeader_Image2\").hide();");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing semicolon(**;**) in your second line

```
String mouseOverScript1 = "var script = document.createElement('script');"
        +"script.src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js';"//semicolon missed here
        +"script.type = 'text/javascript';"
        +"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);";
```

Hope this helps you.Kindly get back if you face any problems

Comment: I am getting two errors now. `SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' 
jquery-2.1.4.min.map, line 1 character 11
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
Default.aspx, line 1 character 1` . Can you test the code in your system and tell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it worked. I replaced the third js file with this one.

```
String mouseOverScript3 = "var script = document.createElement('script');"
            +"script.src ='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js';"
            +"script.type = 'text/javascript';"
            +"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript3);
```

Courtesy - [jQuery 1.6.1 , IE9 and SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203846/jquery-1-6-1-ie9-and-script5009-is-undefined)